# Caching assets in yii 2

Tags: yii, yii2, browser-cache, cache-control, yii2-advanced-app

Is it possible to cache assets, such as js and css, in browser using http control-cache in yii 2? I need to improve my website load time and therefore need to cache my js and css files. I know how to cache a controller action by adding `yii\filters\HttpCache` to the behavior, but is it possible to do the same for assets?

Comment: There is nog really a way to force browsers to chache files localy but yii has a cache for css and js files. maybe varnish https://www.varnish-cache.org/ could help[ you. its a program for the server that caches some files for you (depends on the website you have)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript and CSS should be already cached from browser. If you investigate with firebug, you will see that .js and .css are taken from the cache.